# How to detect when a user leaves web-game lobby

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, websocket, onbeforeunload

I've a basic multiplayer web-game where players get matched in a lobby of 2 when they enter the website. I'm using **nodejs** and **express** for the server side.

**I want the server to detect when a player "*leaves*" the lobby** so that i can then match the remaining player in the lobby with someone else. Leaving should include closing the tab, the browser or refreshing the page.

**I tried** sending an ajax request from the client side when the **"unload"** or **"beforeunload"** events fire. However i found this to be pretty inconsistent and not reliable. I've seen people use **websockets** for managing such client-server communications but never used them. **I thought of** using a timer on the server side to see if a player stops replying which might do the trick. How should i go about implementing this and how do other multiplayer web-games solve this problem?

**Details about my server-side if it helps:** I'm currently using express-session to decide ID's of players. Once the players are in a lobby of 2, they send continuous (every 0.5 seconds) ajax requests to the server to get information about the other player.